# output variables from TCL to a text file

Tags: file-io, tcl

I have three string variables in my TCL script now. Var1 Var2 and Var3.

I want to append them to the end of the output.txt with having blank space between them.

so the added line would be like this:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
```

Comment: Do you want to output the variables' **names** or the variables' **values**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set fp [open output.txt a]
puts $fp "${Var1} ${Var2} ${var3}"
close $fp
```

Answer (score 0):

You would [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm) the file in [append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm#M9) mode. Then, [write the string to the opened channel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/puts.htm). You'll probably want the string to be a [double-quoted string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M8) so variables can be substituted. Then, [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/close.htm) the file.

Comment: I want to output the values, could you provide me the command?